# How do I add an <a> tag attribute to a docusign html document

Tags: docusignapi

This is surely a simple issue. This is what I want. To add an `a` tag to my html document for docusign such that when a user clicks it, they are routed to the link page.

I have done some research on the docusign api docs and indeed the `a` tag and `href` attribute are supported in the api.
Here is my code for creating the `html` document

```
1function document1(data) {
2  // Data for this method
3  // args.signerEmail
4  // args.signerName
5  // args.ccEmail
6  // args.ccName
7
8  return `
9  <!DOCTYPE html>
10  <html>
11     <head>
12      <meta charset="UTF-8">
13      </head>
14      <body style="font-family:sans-serif;margin-left:2em;">
15      <h1 style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
16          color: darkblue;margin-bottom: 0;">THE JANE GOODALL INSTITUTE</h1>
17      <h2 style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
18      margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 3.5em;font-size: 1em;
19      color: darkblue;">Chimpanzee Habitat Improvement Audit</h2>
20      <h4>Ordered by ${data.initiatorName}</h4>
21      <p style="margin-top:0em; margin-bottom:0em;">Email: ${data.initiatorEmail}</p>
22      Below is a snapshot of the current map and changes made to it by 23${data.initiatorName}. 
24      </p>
25      <p style="margin-top:0em; margin-bottom:0em;">If you wish to make changes to the map
26     follow this <a href="https://google.com">link</a> but if you are okay with it 
      pleasesign 
27and agree</p>
28      <!-- Note the anchor tag for the signature field is in white. -->
29      <h3 style="margin-top:3em;">Agreed: <span 30style="color:white;">**signature_1**/</span></h3>
31      </body>
32  </html>`;
33}
```

As you can see on line 26 I am using the a tag as I normally would use it in traditional html. Is there anything I am doing wrong?? Any suggesstions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check/accept the best answer for your question. Thank you! 

Answer (score 0):

It is usually better to include ancillary documents in the envelope itself. They can be included as supplemental documents that are available but not visible by default.

If you still want a link, you can add a link tab via the Envelopes:create API call (not via the HTML).

**[Live example of a link tab](https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/?eg=Hypertext%20link)**

What you can do is create `anchor text` in the HTML. The anchor text will later be used for positioning the tab. Make the anchor text white so it is not visible on the screen. Example of the HTML:

```
<span color="white">/linkAnchor/</span>
```

Then the JSON in the Envelopes:create request

The `tabLabel` must start with `#HREF_`

```
"textTabs": [
              {
                "anchorString": "/linkAnchor/",
                "underline": "true",
                "fontColor": "BrightBlue",
                "fontSize": "Size12",
                "locked": "true",
                "value": "Link text",   // link text
                "required": "true",
                "tabLabel": "#HREF_ExampleLink", 
                "name": "https://www.docusign.com" // link URL
              }
            ]
```